# dynamically generated UIButton in iOS 5 ARC causes deallocated instance crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have a a class I created to generate UIButton's I add to my UIView.  This worked great until my conversion to ARC yesterday, not I get the following error:

```
-[OrderTypeButton performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12449f70
```

Here is the code to add the button to my UIView (actually a subview in my main UIView):

```
OrderTypeButton *btn = [[OrderTypeButton alloc]initWithOrderType:@"All Orders" withOrderCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[self.ordersPlacedList count]] hasOpenOrder:NO];
btn.view.tag = 6969;
btn.delegate = self;
[btn.view setFrame:CGRectMake((col * width)+ colspacer, rowHeight + (row * height),  frameWidth, frameHeight)];
[self.statsView addSubview:btn.view];
```

And here is my class header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol OrderTypeButtonDelegate
-(void) tapped:(id)sender withOrderType:(NSString*) orderType;
@end

@interface OrderTypeButton : UIViewController {
    id<OrderTypeButtonDelegate> __unsafe_unretained delegate;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblOrderType;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblOrderCount;
    NSString *orderType;
    NSString *orderCount;
    BOOL    hasOpenOrder;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *orderButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lblOrderType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lblOrderCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *orderType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *orderCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasOpenOrder;
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<OrderTypeButtonDelegate> delegate;

-(id) initWithOrderType: (NSString *) anOrderType withOrderCount: (NSString *) anOrderCount hasOpenOrder: (BOOL) openOrder;
-(IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "OrderTypeButton.h"

@implementation OrderTypeButton
@synthesize orderButton;
@synthesize lblOrderType, lblOrderCount, orderType, orderCount, hasOpenOrder, delegate;

-(id) initWithOrderType: (NSString *) anOrderType withOrderCount: (NSString *) anOrderCount hasOpenOrder: (BOOL) openOrder {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.orderType = anOrderType;
        self.orderCount = anOrderCount;
        self.hasOpenOrder = openOrder;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.lblOrderType.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.orderType];
    self.lblOrderCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.orderCount];
    if (self.hasOpenOrder) {
        [self.orderButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-order-btn-red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.lblOrderType.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.lblOrderCount.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}

-(IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"TAPPED");
    if ([self delegate] ) {
        [delegate tapped:sender withOrderType:self.orderType];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setOrderButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This seems fairly simple what I am doing here, not sure what changed with ARC that is causing me problems.

Comment: Make sure `statsView` is not `nil` and try to set the buttons delegate to `nil` when the class using it is unloaded or deallocated. `unsafe_unretained` will not zero the reference like `weak` references.

Comment: statsView is a property in my main UIView: @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *statsView;

Comment: It's still possible for it to be `nil` if you forgot to set it. I just recommend you actually make sure it is not `nil` when you add the button to it.

Comment: I added the btn to the may view self.view and am still getting the error so I do not think it is the statsView

Comment: put a breakpoint and try to check or print to see who is receiving the call that is causing the crash.

Comment: I have put break points everywhere but they are never triggered - I believe the btn's are deallocted after they are added to the statsView - I would assume that would hold a reference to them but apparently not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ARC autorelease created button, try to store created buttons in Array

```
//.h file
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *buttonsArray

//.m file
@synthesize buttonsArray
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  buttonsArray = [NSArray array];
...
OrderTypeButton *btn = [[OrderTypeButton alloc]initWithOrderType:@"All Orders"         
                                                  withOrderCount:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[self.ordersPlacedList count]]
                                                    hasOpenOrder:NO];
btn.view.tag = 6969;
btn.delegate = self;
[btn.view setFrame:CGRectMake((col * width)+ colspacer, rowHeight + (row * height),  frameWidth, frameHeight)];
[self.statsView addSubview:btn.view];
//Add button to array
[buttonsArray addObject:btn];
```

Also this approach will help if you want to change buttons, or remove some specific button from view

Comment: That did it,  seems like some weird behavior - wonder where else this is going to popup in my app :(

Comment: @Slee this should not be necessary, you should try to track down the cause of this issue.